# Trying to echo ^^ in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping

I am making batch animations, and to make nostrils I want to echo 2 carets, or `^^`, but only one is displayed.

How do I stop/bypass the escape property of the caret character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could double them up and get the result you are looking for.

```
echo ^^^^
```

Answer (score 5):

Well technically, the caret `^` character *is* the escape character.

If you're wanting to display 2 carets, you can simply "escape the escape character".

The correct string to display 2 carets is below:

```
echo ^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to escaping the escape character (`^^`), you could use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```cmd
rem // Assign variable with `^` protected by `""`:
set "STR=^^"
rem // Use delayed expansion which happens after escaping:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !STR!
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of other ways to do this.

Use the FOR command.

```
for %%G IN ("^^") do echo %%~G
```

Use `SET /P` with `NUL` redirection.  This one has some caveats. You can't put any spaces before the carets.  If you need spaces before the carets there is another hack you can use with the backspace character.

```
<nul set /p ".=^^" &echo(
```

Comment: Nice (+1), although the first one has some caveats too: when delayed expansion is enabled and the entire string contains `!`-marks, escaping applies again, even twice (once when parsing the `for` loop header, once when parsing its body). And the second approach does not allow `=` as the first character...

Comment: @aschipfl, can probably use the backspace trick with the `SET /P` solution.